# Error in Routing - Strongly Typed Angular 2 with asp.net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, angular

I am working on a strongly typed Angular2 and MVC6 project. Idea is to use **Razor + Angular**.

When I try to do

`templateUrl : 'Home/Index'` // Expecting MVC controller to load the                                                   Index.cshtml

I get an error
`Potentially unhandled rejection [3] t@http://localhost:41860/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js:6:5082
_</e.prototype.normalizeLoadedTemplate@http://localhost:41860/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js:15:19192
_</e.prototype.normalizeTemplate/<@http://localhost:41860/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js:15:18927`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfdNz.png)

On the other hand,  when I comment **Layout** section in _**view.cshtml** it works (I still see issues loading child routes). Loading angular2 dependencies in **Index.cshtml** rather than **_Layout.cshtml** (tried other way too).

But, when I reference a plain HTML file, it works.

`templateUrl : 'path/app.html'` // This works without an error.

I did not encounter this error when I worked with angular **0.46 aplha** and I see this after upgrading it to angular **2.0 Beta**.

Looking for some inputs!

Comment: Look at the browser network tab and see the html that is returned on home/index request. Is valid html being returned

Comment: I would suggest showing the first loaded page of the angular2 SPA.  And show the _view.cshtml + layout of home/index.  It seems like  you might be reloading the first page in the call to home/index which doesn't make any sense